# d3.js radial clock, adding dots instead of clock hands

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a radial clock, but instead of clock arms, I need to have dots at the end of every path indicating time (blue). Thanks for the help!

Edit: like this: https://puu.sh/sH03Y/c59281fb5e.png

Line drawing part:

```
var clockLine = linesLayer.selectAll('.clock-line')
.data(fields);

 clockLine.enter().append('line')
.attr('class', function (d) { return 'line clock-line ' + d.id; })
.attr('x1', 0).attr('y1', 0);
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zh3owyr3/

Comment: What do you mean by "dots at the end of every path indicating time (blue)"? Like hour indicators?

Comment: Like this example: https://puu.sh/sH03Y/c59281fb5e.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `<line>`, append a `<circle>`:

```
var clockCircle = linesLayer.selectAll('.clock-line')
    .data(fields);

clockCircle.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return 'circle clock-circle ' + d.id;
    })
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("fill", "teal");
```

And change its position in the `tick` function:

```
clockCircle.attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.index * radius * Math.cos(d.value * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2);
})
.attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.index * radius * Math.sin(d.value * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2);
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mjru5ta8/

PS: you'll have to change your viewbox to avoid the seconds' circle being cropped.